# Cookie vanishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

Im developing a login and user DB system for a customer. The problem i have is that i am trying to register user devices in an attempt to limit how meny devices a given user can use to log on within a month. this is all working just fine, however i am having a issue with the cookie im saving at the client computer.

Even though im setting the expiredate as shown in the code below, Internet Explorer deletes the cookie at the end of the session. It's working just fine in Chrome. 
Set cookie code:

```
                cookie = new HttpCookie("DeviceLog");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                cookie.Values.Add("DeviceId", guid.ToString());
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Retrive cookie code:

```
                HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["DeviceLog"];
```

I admit that my knowlege about cookies are limitet, so it's propperly something fairly obivius, however i havnt been able to solve it, even after an hour on Google :p

Update, entire cookie code snippet:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            Response.Redirect(STSUtility.GetRefereUrl(true));
        }
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            try {
                if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null) {
                    username.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
                    password.Attributes["value"] = AESEncrypter.Decrypt(Request.Cookies["Password"].Value);
                    remember.Checked = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (remember.Checked) {
            Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        } else {
            Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        }
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = username.Text.Trim();
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = AESEncrypter.EncryptToken(password.Text.Trim());

        MembershipProvider mp = new MembershipProvider();
        bool userValidated = mp.ValidateUser(username.Text, password.Text);

        if (userValidated && Page.IsValid) {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["DeviceLog"];
            ContextDataContext model = new ContextDataContext();
            User user = model.Users.First(x => x.Email == username.Text.Trim());

            Session["UserId"] = user.Id.ToString();
            int userDevices = model.UserDevicesLogs.Count(x => x.UserId == user.Id);

            if (!user.Active) {
                return;
            }

            if (userDevices >= maxDeviceLoginsPrUser && cookie == null) {
                Response.Redirect("/Sites/Login/ExceedMaxDevices.aspx");
            }

            if (cookie == null) {//Hvis device ikke har en cookie
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

                cookie = new HttpCookie("DeviceLog");

                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                cookie.Values.Add("DeviceId", guid.ToString());
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                model.UserDevicesLogs.InsertOnSubmit(new UserDevicesLog {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    DeviceId = guid,
                    LastLoginFromDevice = DateTime.Now
                });
            } else {//Hvis device har en cookie
                Guid deviceId;
                Guid.TryParse(cookie.Values["DeviceId"], out deviceId);

                UserDevicesLog deviceLog = model.UserDevicesLogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.Id && x.DeviceId == deviceId);

                if (deviceLog == null) {
                    model.UserDevicesLogs.InsertOnSubmit(new UserDevicesLog {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        DeviceId = deviceId,
                        UserId = user.Id,
                        LastLoginFromDevice = DateTime.Now
                    });
                } else {
                    deviceLog.LastLoginFromDevice = DateTime.Now;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }

            model.SubmitChanges();

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.Text, remember.Checked);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])) {
                Response.Redirect(STSUtility.GetRefereUrl(true));
            } else {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Email, remember.Checked);
            }

        }
    }
```

It's only the DeviceLog cookie thats giving me the issue...

Comment: It is working just fine in the Chrome browser, however Internet Explorer and FireFox is treating the cookie as a session cookie, rather than setting the 30 days expire date.

Comment: Just now tested your code, your code is working fine, I can read cookie from IE, I'm using IE 11

Comment: Would you like to post some more code? e.g. code in Page Load, Page Init and some in the master page etc.

Comment: Did you forgot to add the cookie at page load..??

Comment: ehh i only got read code in page load, it's not suppose to add cookies, creating the cookie is all handled in the btnLogin_Cklick event...

Comment: Do you mean you aren't able to access ALL cookies? (Including UserName and Password)

Comment: No it is only the DeviceLog cookie thats dosent seem to work propperly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved this myself, finally....

I had Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); twise in the code, wich was the cause. Not sure why exatly that would be a problem since it was the same cookie added twise, and yea.. stupid stupid stupid i know :) Thanks for the sudgestions, im happy to finally have this resolved :)